# Why git doesn't merge/rebase with fetched master?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

So, I have this history :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY3Oh.png)
When I try to merge/rebase and get this.. :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZexL.png)

What is wrong, ?  Please, help.
Contents of these branch is different, but why merge/rebase doesn't execute?

Comment: [Please don't post images of your code in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557). Also, please use markdown correctly in order to embed _relevant_ images.

Comment: ok, i've got it ) sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshots, `master` and `feature/43042` branches both point to the same commit. So the contents of the branches are not different. Perhaps you want to rebase on top of `origin/master`?

`git rebase origin/master`

Comment: Many thanks !   somehow after `pull origin master` i've got my `master` detached from `origin/master`,  while changes were made   at `feature/43042`